# Pulling and assigning Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, sockets

This is a hack of socket.io's web sockets using Node and Jquery. The idea is to send an html page to all the clients (rather than the actual message I would have typed in a typical chat). So far, I've gotten the "send" part of the chat to send the selected value of a drop down (so I can send any one of a series of html page number I want - page 1-18 for example) which will then be used to include the appropriate html page.

In the following code, msg now displays the page number I selected (from the admin panel) on all the listening clients. What I need to do is replace that numerical value with the actual html code of a page of a similar name (page1.html, page2.html etc). The pages are/will be stored in either the same location (or one directory level lower would be better).

The line with the Get was my attempt (plus numerous others) to do this but, in this case, I can't even get the alert to trigger?

Question 1 (just for a newbie in Javascript) is why won't the alert trigger?

Question 2 How can I get the html code of a page1.html to become the "msg"?

Thanks!

```
<script>
$(function () {
    var socket = io();

    $('form').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
    });

    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        $.get('page1.txt', function(msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }, "text");
        $('#messages').text(msg);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. Explain the sending html page part?

Comment: Perhaps I should have better explained it is a hack of a chat room script. I want it to be just a one-way "chat" and I just want to replace the content that the server would normally send (i.e. whatever I type) with html code from a list of pages I can choose (like sending a Powerpoint window through the Internet).